# playstation3 via hdmi input on ubuntu audio issue

Tags: 13.04, sound, ati, hdmi

I have an AlienWare m17xr3 laptop with switchable Radeon HD6990 and HDMI input.

When I connect a playstation 3 everything works fine, but there is no sound.

Has anyone any idea why there is no sound or how to fix it?

Comment: A lot of HDMI on laptops only supports video, might be that.

Answer (score 0):

**"Pulse Audio Volume Control"** Application may be your answer or may not.

Download it from Software Center and then check the devices under Input Devices Tab.